# Why is it showing me this error in android studio with a project i importet from git

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open cp_init remapped class cache for dw5ezsq9vnujkjvxyvhfx35dd (C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\5.6.2\scripts-remapped\ijmapper_7gc8vtmeowga3sem0k6ykyb01\dw5ezsq9vnujkjvxyvhfx35dd\cp_init40e7ec637808a9c747559d26950b1d9b).
> Could not open cp_init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ijmapper.gradle' (C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\5.6.2\scripts\dw5ezsq9vnujkjvxyvhfx35dd\cp_init\cp_init40e7ec637808a9c747559d26950b1d9b).
   > Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.Verifier

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s
```

Comment: Please write a full question, at the moment you have only posted an error trace without any question. Also don't forget to include important details like used version(s) of Android Studio, Java, gradle...

Answer (score 1):

It might be a Problem with Compatibility try downgrading your java to version 1.8 by going file -> settings -> search for gradle -> select the jvm to version 1.8 ok
If the problem still going imma have to ask you to post the gradle version - gradle plugin version for this project